# Creating new data frame using group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having data frame like this:

```
cust_id   s1   s2 
  1      100   0
  2      100   1
  3      90    1
  4      85    0
  5      90    1
```

and I'm trying to get the following output:

```
 s1    s1(Count)  s2(sum)
 100     2          1
 90      2          2
 85      1          0
```

I tried to use `groupby` and `size/sum` (like in here: [Pandas: Create a new Data Frame using multiple GroupBy results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779286/pandas-create-a-new-data-frame-using-multiple-groupby-results)):

e.g., 
`abc = df.groupby(by="s1")["s1","s2"].sum()` ## *I don't know how to create count for s1 and sum for s2*

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: That's explained quite well in the documentation: [Applying different functions to dataframe columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns).

Comment: my problem is that I'm changing the data frame dimensions (and I can't do it without implying the _"agg"_ functions (sum and count). It has to happened together. Can you please clarify the right way of doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Try this: `df.groupby(by="s1")["s2"].agg(['size', 'sum'])`

Comment: Thank you very much. When I'm looking on it, it seems so intuitive :)